# Controller method is not called second time

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton, actionfunction

I am calling controller function on command button click.

This is button:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Add" onClick="addItemToCard('{!$Component.bVAL}', '{!item.Id}'); return false;"/>
```

This is actionFunction:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="addToCardFunction" action="{!addToCard}" reRender="items"> 
    <apex:param name="count" value="" assignTo="{!itemCount}"/> 
    <apex:param name="id" value="" assignTo="{!itemId}"/> 
</apex:actionFunction>
```

I call controller function in js:

```
function addItemToCard(itemCountId, id) { 
    addToCardFunction(document.getElementById(itemCountId).value, id); 
}
```

I don't know why, but my addToCard() controller method is called only in the first time . When I click button second time, nothing happens. Page is just reloaded :(

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be to do with your use of an `apex:commandButton`. Since you are just calling a Javascript function, just use a regular button like so:

```
<button onclick="addItemToCard('{!$Component.bVAL}', '{!item.Id}'); return false;">Add</button>
```

Normally with a `commandButton` you would call an action method directly - not doing that could cause issues.